# PCRE: How to get name capture with pcrecpp

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I wanna know how to get a named capture with `pcrecpp` for *PCRE*. Let's assume i have the following regex:

```
\\*{5}\\s+Hand\\s+History\\s+for\\s+Game\\s+((?P<HANDNAME>)\\w+)\\s+\\*{5}
```

How can I get the result of `((?P<HANDNAME>)\\w+)` with named and not with numbered capturing? 
I only know the method `FullMatch`. How can I say get match of `HANDNAME`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. C level PCRE would give you [pcre_get_named_substring](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcre_get_named_substring), but that's not exposed by the C++ class, and the original `pcre*` is private.